# error loading csv file for R

Tags: r, csv, load-csv

when i loading csv file for R, i can see the error 
but i don't know why this happening

### i wrote following code:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\규남\\Desktop\\twitter")
library(KoNLP)
useSejongDic()
txt <- readLines(file("test.csv"))
```

### and, this error appear

```
txt <- readLines(file("test.csv"))
Error in readLines(file("test.csv")) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file("test.csv")) :
  cannot open file 'test.csv': No such file or directory
```

why this happening?
file directory is not wrong, and that file in the folder
[enter image description here][1]
please see this 
i restart Rstudio, even notebook power
but error appear again
how to i load that csv file?
and why this happening?
here is result useing `getwd()` function

```
[1] "C:/Users/규남/Desktop/twitter"
Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (test.csv) 

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFkt.png
```

Comment: `\ ` has a special meaning. Try using `/` instead in `setwd()`

Comment: same error appear in console

Comment: Is your file listed when you run `dir()`?

Comment: what's mean dir()? you mean that i open that file,at the same time, i run that coding?

Comment: `dir()` shows the files in the working directory. Most likely, your working directory is not what you expect, or you are mistyping the file name. `file.choose()` can be very useful.

Comment: following your suggestion, i write code like this : "txt <-readLines(file(file.choose()))" and i choose file that i want load csv file. 
but this error appear
Warning messages:
1: closing unused connection 4 (test.csv) 
2: closing unused connection 3 (test.csv) 
i don't know why this happening
should i try to delect R and R studio and reset program?

Comment: did it work? better to use `myfile <- file.choose()` then `readLines(myfile)` ie delete the `file()`

Comment: perfact!! thank you very much! how to i vote you? when i tried this code, "txt <-readLines(file(file.choose()))"  can work but still exist error i think that code cause error. but your suggestion can be work no error and load perfact! thank you very much. you save my life!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working through these problems I like to use the `file.path()` function.  Look at the documentation, but it makes certain that the separator characters that are used in the string are what R is expecting.

Try:

```
path <- file.path("C:", "Users", "규남", "Desktop", "twitter")
setwd(path)
library(KoNLP)
useSejongDic()
txt <- readLines(file("test.csv"))
```

Comment: this way still view same error. i didn't know why this happening. but following your reply suggestion, using 'file.choose()' function, the error disappear!

Comment: may be....korean laguage using in file directory '규남', so this happening appear i think.